# How can I change all input values to uppercase using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change all my form values to uppercase before the form is submitted.

So far I have this but it's not working.

```
$('#id-submit').click(function () {
        var allInputs = $(":input");
        $(allInputs).value.toUpperCase();
        alert(allInputs);
});
```

Comment: `allInputs.val().toUpperCase()`

Comment: [Learn about `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey val() only gets the value of the fist element

Comment: sorry, i should have put more context. if you're using jQuery, you should use jQuery .val() instead of vanilla JS .value. that's all i was trying to get across, sorry for the confusion. hence comment, not answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('input[type=text]').val (function () {
    return this.value.toUpperCase();
})
```

You should use `input[type=text]` instead of `:input` or `input` as I believe your intention are to operate on textbox only.

Comment: $(allInputs) should actually be $(":input"), no need to double $

Answer (score 18):

use css :

```
input.upper { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

probably best to use the style, and convert serverside. There's also a jQuery plugin to force uppercase: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/uppercase

Comment: NOTE: this will just display the text in uppercase, it wont convert the values to be saved that way.

Comment: @GustavoReyes as this answer says, you really need to do the conversion at the server anyway. You can't be certain that the client-side code will be run.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#id-submit').click(function () {
    $("input").val(function(i,val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uJL7k/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Use css text-transform to display text in all input type text.
In Jquery you can then transform the value to uppercase on blur event.

Css:

```
input[type=text] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('blur', "input[type=text]", function () {
    $(this).val(function (_, val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks i change the input[type="text"]..for class="uppercase"... works for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('#id-submit').click(function () {
      $(":input").each(function(){
          this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();          
      });
});
```

Comment: *"This works like a charm"* until it comes across a select element.